# Lookup for Certain Text if so..Copy cell value of the same Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I'm trying to do the following.
I got two sheets on the same worksheet.

Sheet A:

[image]

Sheet B:

[image]

When i check the checkbox on the Modules Filter (Drones) i need to fill a list with TYPENAME(Sheet B) that contains only Modules that belong to the "Drones" groupName (Sheet B)

Thx!

Comment: You can put a pivot table in Sheet A. And use GroupName as a filter and TypeID as row. For better usage, you can use a slicer.

Comment: It doesn't really work out for me to be honest. I would have to manually delete groupNames than i don't use or want.

Comment: So, your "Module" filter is the "GroupName" column. Correct?  [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C19V.png) is how the pivot table would look like, which is pretty much serve your purpose (except that those are not checkboxes).  Please be more specific on which part that didn't work for you (or how you want things to be shown).